# How to view formatted iotop log file in terminal with a cat

Tags: linux, io

So I have logged the history of Disk usage with a iotop  > iohis.log

How can I view the file so it is formatted nicely and I can actually find the issue.
I thought I could use the cat but it just fast worwards the whole text. =(.
Could you give me any hints on how to view log file in a nice way?

Comment: I understand it is lame but I really need it. please help

Comment: Step one: hold cat in hands. Step two: lift cat towards monitor....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `cat`. It just displays the whole file content and then it exits.

You have to use `less`. Also, you can combine `grep` and `less` to find some specific pattern. For example:

```
$ grep error /path/to/file | less
```

There are many other useful utilities available. Here are some: `head`, `tail`, and `awk`...

Comment: You can also search within `less`. Press `/` then type the regex you're looking for and press enter. Or `less -p pattern` to start the search from the command line. Also, `less` can scroll left and right if the output is wider than the terminal. Use `-S` to prevent wrapping (and `-#1` for horizontal scrolling interval if you're on a fast terminal).

Comment: You can also use `?` to search backward. Use letter 'n' for next and letter 'N' for previous.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's not the editor ... it's the way you "grab" it.

try to use batch mode (-b flag)

By default iotop (like top) are running in interactive mode.

Comment: Yes exactly as u said "interactive mode" - is there a way to simulate that interactive mode with a log file ?

Comment: Wait ... what do you want to do ? You have the history of iotop (given with batch mode) and you want to see how it was evolved in time ?  I 'm sorry but i 'm not completely sure that i understand what you want to do.

Comment: O well I just want to see the saved history without unrecognized characters

Answer (score 0):

Try `less -R /path/to/iohis.log`. Not perfect, but shows your log at least in a bit more readable form.